# Accessing Google Calendar data from native Android app using hard-coded credentials

Tags: android, oauth, google-calendar-api, accountmanager

I'm developing an Android app which presents Google Calendar data for a specific Google account (which the users do NOT have access to). I understand GData does not support Android, so I'm using Google APIs Client Library for Java instead. I don't want to save the credentials in the Account Manager, since they're private, and I can't use OAuth since that requires the user to type the credentials into a webpage via redirection, and the user obviously doesn't know the credentials. Any ideas?

tl;dr: Want to access Google Calendar data for a specific account without providing the user with credentials or giving them any power over the account.

Comment: Have you found your solution for this matter? I'm stuck on same things for few days already. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to only support Ice Cream Sandwich and above, you can use the new [Calendar.Contracts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html) API. But other than that, I highly doubt you're going to find anything that meets your criteria.